# Trying to remove the first column of a document.

Tags: regex, vim

I'm using this command below to remove the first column of a document:

```
%s/^[^\t]*\zs\t[^\t]*\ze//g
```

but it says command not found. Any idea?

Comment: Do you start command-line typing with hitting colon? Don't you use `S` instead of `s`?

Comment: Add a few lines of text on which you are working on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you delete a column of text in Vim / Vi / gVim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028413/can-you-delete-a-column-of-text-in-vim-vi-gvim)

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/241604/trying-to-remove-the-first-column-of-a-document).

Answer (score 14):

Here's the quickest way to remove the first column:

1. Press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to go to the first character in the document.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual block mode.
3. Hit <kbd>G</kbd> (that is, shift-g) to go to the end of the document
4. Hit <kbd>x</kbd> to delete the first column.

Comment: har, i posted that on SU (see cross post) .. but then deleted it because it is unclear if the first char already makes the first column .. :)

Comment: This seems to delete the column with the first character, not necessarily the first column. If you want to delete a column of whitespace, for example, this won't work.

Answer (score 4):

I like the block selection solution of @Peter, but if you want to use substitution you need this command:

```
:%s/^.//
```

Let's analyze why this works:

- `:%s` exec a substitution on all the document
- `/^./` select the first character after the start of the line
- `/` and replace it with... nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the job:

```
:%s/^[^\t]//
```

The command removes all leading characters that are not a tabulator.

Alternatively, if you're editing a *tabulator separated values* document and want to remove all "columns" before the first tabulator, then this should do it for you:

```
%s/^[^\t]*\t//
```

Comment: %s/^[^\t]*\t// worked fro me. It deleted the first column in a tab-del-file.

Answer (score 0):

The below command worked for me:

```
:%s/^\w*//
```