# Change all characters in a column over multiple lines

Tags: vim, multiple-columns, edit

I'm not sure how to explain what I'd like to do, but I've seen this in Textmate and it was quite useful. Let's say I have this text:

```
:aa => foo,
:ab => foo,
:ac => foo,
:ad => foo
```

Now I want to select all first characters of the keys (the 4 'a' in the lne) and remove them, so that the result looks like this:

```
:a => foo,
:b => foo,
:c => foo,
:d => foo
```

Some kind of visual mode accounting columns not lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use vim in column mode. To use it, press:

> 1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to go into column mode.
> 2. Select the columns and rows where you want to enter your text.
> 3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to go into insert mode in column mode.
> 4. Type in the text you want to enter.
>
>    <sup>Note: Don't be discouraged by the fact that only the first row is changed.</sup>
> 5. Esc to apply your change (or alternately <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
>
> You will now see your changed applied.

Source: [Column Edit Mode in VI](http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/column-edit-mode-in-vi).

Comment: Please explain the solution here, do not just link to it.

Comment: The current location of the article is https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/column-edit-mode-in-vi but the answer is too short to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to enter blockwise visual mode. You can then select a block of text using the normal movement keys and press <kbd>x</kbd> to delete it. <kbd>I</kbd> will perform a multi-line insert.

See `:help ^V` and `:help visual-operators` in vim for full details.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ctrl-V to select in block mode, then directional and editing commands to do the rest. See
[How to remove quotes surrounding the first two columns in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028413/can-you-delete-a-column-of-text-in-vim-vi-gvim)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Visual Block mode, which is accessible by `Ctrl+V` in Normal mode. Works just like `Alt+select` in TextMate.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said `Ctrl-V` is the answer.  For a tutorial see [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episode "[Selecting columns with visual block mode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/selecting-columns-with-visual-block-mode/)"

Answer (score 0):

In your special case:

```
:% s/a/
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a search and replace to specifically remove the first letter of the lines that start with a colon:

```
:%s/:./:
```