# Replace misaligned columns in vim

Tags: vim, replace, field

I have seen many posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916444/change-all-characters-in-a-column-over-multiple-lines), that tell how to replace text column wise in vim.

That is straightforward when columns are arranged with fixed widths.

How about using vim to replace text in a given column when the columns are not aligned.

E.g.

I have a file with multiple columns:

```
col1 -col2 0.col3 +col4  col5.
col1  0.col2 +col3  col4.0  -col5
col1.0 0.col2 +col3  -col4 col5
col1 col2.0  +col3 0.col4  -col5
-col1 col2.0  +col3 0.col4  col5
col1 -col2  +col3 0.col4  col5.0
```

and I want it to look like

```
col1       0.col3 +col4  col5.
col1         +col3  col4.0  -col5
col1.0        +col3  -col4 col5
col1         +col3 0.col4  -col5
-col1         +col3 0.col4  col5
col1        +col3 0.col4  col5.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Here is a convoluted solution using a substitution:

  ```
  :%s/^\S*\s*\zs\(\S*\)/\=repeat(" ", len(submatch(1)))/g
  ```

  See `:help :s`, `:help submatch()`, `:help repeat()`.
- And here is a *much* simpler one using a macro:

  ```
  :%normal WvEr <-- there's a space after the 'r'
  ```

  See `:help :normal`.

Comment: You don't have to add `\ze` at the end of pattern if there is nothing after !

Comment: The `normal` cmd is not correct it should be `:%normal WvEr ` !!

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`:%s/^\(.\{-}. \)\{1}\zs\(.\{-}. \)/     /g`

You can change `\{1}` to desired column number, note that is 1 less than actual column number. Also you can modify this regex a little more to erase multiple consecutive columns. And so on and so forth.

for transform this:

```
col1 -col2 0.col3 +col4  col5.
col1  0.col2 +col3  col4.0  -col5
col1.0 0.col2 +col3  -col4 col5 
col1 col2.0  +col3 0.col4  -col5
-col1 col2.0  +col3 0.col4  col5 
col1 -col2  +col3 0.col4  col5.0
```

to this:

```
col1       0.col3 +col4  col5.
col1       +col3  col4.0  -col5
col1.0       +col3  -col4 col5
col1        +col3 0.col4  -col5
-col1        +col3 0.col4  col5
col1        +col3 0.col4  col5.0
```