# Deleting column in vim

Tags: vim

I want to delete the first column of a text file using vim. 
I read these [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028413/can-you-delete-a-column-of-text-in-vim-vi-gvim) where visual mode is used, but they only delete the first character (as for the answers using patters, I don't understand them so I have trouble adapting them to my situation).

My file contains many numbers and I want to delete the numbers in the first column, not just the first element.

eg

```
12 34 43143 1
131234 1 
1 3443 132
```

I would like to have

```
34 43143 1
1 
3443 132
```

but currently, I get

```
2 34 43143 1
31234 1 
 3443 132
```

The numbers are separated by tabs if it matters

Comment: No need of visual mode. How about a regular expression?

Comment: @Birei could you give me a clue of how to do that please?

Comment: How about `%s/\v^\d*\s//g` , not tested but should work

Comment: Could you explain me these commands please? (I'd like to learn how to use RE)

Comment: \v stands for very magic , it is not turned on so basically its not default, \d stands for digit, * stands for 0 or more number of times, \s stands for space and % stands for current file , %s stands for search the current file and g stands for global substitute, by the way carret stands for start of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test this : `%s/\v^\d*\s//g` , you can replace `\s` with `\t` if it is tab delimited,

`\v` stands for very magic , it is not turned on so basically its not default and it is used for avoiding masking of parenthesis("(" ),curly brackets("{") e.t.c with slashes, `\d` stands for digit, * stands for 0 or more number of times of matches, `\s` stands for space and % stands for current file , `%s` stands for search the current file and `g` stands for global substitute, by the way carret(`^`) stands for start of the line, In this case you don't have to use `\v` and `g` , but i use it anyways.

**Edit:**
So this is perfectly fine : `%s/^\d*\s//` , **Thanks to Jeff**

You can use vim help for something like

```
:h \v
:h \d
```

e.t.c to get their formal definitions

Comment: The `\v` option isn't needed here.  It will work the same if those two characters are omitted.

Comment: Thanks I know it is not needed , its just my habit to put it. Thanks anyways , i have put that however in my paragraph

Answer (score 7):

This is a job for `cut`!

```
:%!cut -f 2-
```

Answer (score 6):

(Integer) numbers are represented by `[0-9]` in regular expression syntax, you can also write `\d`; as there are many digits, the quantifier `\+` is appended. A tab it `\t`, or generally whitespace is `\s`. Now, you want to replace / `:substitute` the number at the beginning of a line(`^`) with nothing.

```
:%s/^\d\+\t//
```

The `%` applies this to the entire buffer, see `:help :range`.

#### and beyond

Soon, you'll want to delete different columns; you can assert certain matches (e.g. `^\d\+\t\zs\d\+\t` would select the second column), or use *capture groups* (with which you can even re-order columns!) But it'll be more tedious.

A breakthrough happens when you realize that your file format is well-known by the name *tab-separated values*, a variant of *comma-separated values* (CSV). There's a great plugin for that ([csv.vim - A Filetype plugin for csv files](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=2830), and it has a `:DeleteColumn` command - just what you needed! (And more...)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is using a Macro:

```
qq0dawjq
```

Then you have to use the macro with:**@q**  or **3@q**  or **whatever number + @q**

Explanation:

```
q: Start Recording a Macro
q: Save the macro in register q
0: Go to the beginning of the line
daw: Delete A Word
j: Move down to the next line
q: Finish the recording
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do type

```
:%s/\d\+\t//
```